# How to engage a custom module in a Send Mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to disable WS-Security for incoming Response of my secured Request. The request is secured by Policy in send mediator like this:

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <address format="soap11" uri="${endpoint}">
      <enableSec policy="conf:policies/Policy.xml" />
    </address>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

For disabling WS-Security on incoming messages I followed this article [SOA Security - Disabling WS-Security for IN or OUT messages in Axis2](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/11/09/disabling-ws-security-for-in-or-out-messages-in-axis2/). It uses a custom module to replace Policy file for the message validation.
For writing custom module and engaging it inside my services I followed [Writing an Axis2 Module](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Writing+an+Axis2+Module) and [Engaging Module](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Modules#WorkingwithModules-Engagingmodules) from WSO2 documentation.

If i engage the module globally by adding nosecurity module to *axis2.xml*, it works for every incoming message like its supposed to.

```
<!-- ================================================= -->
<!--             Global Engaged Modules                -->
<!-- ================================================= -->

<!-- Comment this out to disable Addressing -->
<module ref="addressing"/>
<module ref="nosecurity"/>
```

But I don't know how to engage the module only for the Send Mediator.
When using this proxy from [Engaging Module](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Modules#WorkingwithModules-Engagingmodules), it only engages the module for incoming requests to this proxy and not to the request of my call to an endpoint with Send Mediator.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Pass"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <send>
        <endpoint>
          <address format="soap11" uri="${endpoint}">
            <enableSec policy="conf:policies/Policy.xml" />
          </address>
        </endpoint>
      </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="engagedModules">nosecurity</parameter>
</proxy>
```

So my question is, how do i engage my custom Axis2 module only for the Send Mediator? Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You can engage modules at service level too.
Please check **To engage a module at service level** at [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Modules#WorkingwithModules-Engagingmodules

Comment: Thank you for a response. In the last part of my question I mentioned using a proxy with the parameter **<parameter name="engagedModules">nosecurity</parameter>**. But by adding this parameter my module is engaged only at the input of the proxy service and not on the output where I send a request to another endpoint.
This is the part where I need to engage the module: **<send><endpoint><address format="soap11" uri="${endpoint}"><enableSec policy="conf:policies/Policy.xml" /></address></endpoint></send>**